# Odata Ax7 Integration

Tags: .net, microsoft-dynamics

I am getting an error like of type `System.InvalidOperationException`

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.OData.Client.dll
>   Additional information: The key property 'Type' on for type 
>   'ProductsApp4.Microsoft.Dynamics.DataEntities.LegalEntityContact' is of 
>   type 'System.Nullable`1[[ProductsApp4.Microsoft.Dynamics.DataEntities.LogisticsElectronicAddressMethodType, ProductsApp4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]', which is not a simple type. Only properties of simple type can be key properties.

Here is the code the error occurs:

```
private static void ReadLegalEntities(Resources context)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (var legalEntity in context.LegalEntities.AsEnumerable())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}", legalEntity.Name);
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I see this is related to using Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations (formerly Dynamics Ax7) data entities. According the closed support issue referenced below from the Dynamics integration GitHub repo, there are custom oData client DLLs that need to be used to avoid this error when consuming D365 entities in .NET.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Dynamics-AX-Integration/issues/34

> Use the custom OData dlls in
>   https://github.com/Microsoft/Dynamics-AX-Integration/tree/master/Packages
>   This should solve the issue.

Comment: Actually I just tried this while researching this same issue, and I couldn't get it to work using the "custom DLLs" as mentioned above.

Comment: I also couldn't get it to work. I get this error now: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Client' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key.